# Rust module files in deep directories

Tags: rust

I am new to Rust and try to understand the module system. As there has been a change with the 2018 version I get confused when watching tutorials and there seems to be no documentation talking about including files in deep directories. I got a working project but want to optimize it, as it seems very verbose.

I have the following file structure:

```
.
|-- Cargo.toml
`-- src
    |-- cmds
    |   |-- install_cmd
    |   |   |-- install.rs
    |   |   `-- ...
    |   `-- start_cmd
    |       |-- start.rs
    |       `-- ...
    `-- main.rs
```

Notice that install.rs and start.rs are two subfolders deep (src/cmds/install_cmd/install.rs).
The files install.rs and start.rs are both quite simple:

```
// start.rs looks similar
pub fn handle_install_command() {
     ...
}
```

Now to use install.rs and start.rs, which are two subfolders deep, I have to write the following in my main.rs:

```
mod cmds {
    pub mod install_cmd {
        pub mod install;
    }

    pub mod start_cmd {
        pub mod start;
    }
}

use cmds::{install_cmd::install::handle_install_command, start_cmd::start::handle_start_command};

fn main() {
     handle_install_command();
     handle_start_command();
}
```

The mod declaration seems very verbose to me. Is there a better way to handle this, instead of writing lines of module declaration, just to import a file? Just writing pub mod install does not seem to work, when I am using something from two subfolder deep. Also I read that using multiple mod files is discouraged by now, but I do not want to write so many boilerplate lines in every file in the root directory that uses subsub(sub)directory files.

Comment: I would rename `install_cmd` into plain `install`, then either move `install.rs` into `cmds` or rename is to `mod.rs`. This removes one useless level of nesting from your module structure. I would also avoid repeating the module name in the function names (i.e. rename `handle_install_command` to plain `handle`). Then just call it with `cmds::install::handle()`, or `use cmds::install` and `install::handle()`.

Comment: Also rather than duplicating the `mod` hierarchy inside `main.rs`, it is customary to just declare direct children (so here only `mod cmds`), and have a `cmds.rs` or `cmds/mod.rs` that declares its children (e.g. `pub mod install; pub mod start;`) and so on recursively. This makes it easier to move whole module hierarchies when reorganizing the code.

Comment: If I put it all in the cmds folder, the folder would get too bloated. I have multiple commands beside install and start and all of them use several files. The mod.rs file in cmd folder might be what I am looking for.  You are also right on the handle() name, but I stripped the problem down for this question and used a generic name :D. Thx

Comment: I didn't say to put it all into the `cmds` folder. E.g. for the `install` command only `install.rs` should go into `cmds`, then the other files related to the `install` command should go into the `install` folder like now.